# Compare the average value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

### I have a  pandas dataframe with records for football match

### Now what I need to do is:

### > Find all teams whose average score playing as a home team is lower than its average score playing as an away team. For each team, return the team, its average score in home games, and its average score in away games

### I know how to calculate the average value of HomeScore and AwayScore:

### mean_Homescore = df.groupby(["Home"])["HomeScore"].mean()

but I don't know how to compare them. Sorry if it is too easy, just getting started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually compare the 2 `Series` directly. This will give you a mask with which you can select the teams you're interested in:

```
print(mean_Homescore[mean_Homescore < mean_Awayscore].index)
```

[demo](https://repl.it/repls/MintcreamAlphanumericDeprecatedsoftware)

You can read the above snippet as "print `mean_Homescore` *where* `mean_Homescore` is less than `mean_Awayscore`." Looking at `.index` simply shows us the team names, rather than the team name and associated `mean_Homescore`.

Comment: nice,thacks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
mean_Homescore = df.groupby(["Team Home"])["HomeScore"].mean()
mean_Awayscore = df.groupby(["Team Away"])["AwayScore"].mean()
```

Concat both Series using:

```
mean_Home_Away = pd.concat([mean_Homescore, mean_Awayscore], axis = 1)
```

Finally:

```
mean_Home_Away[mean_Home_Away["AwayScore"] > mean_Home_Away["HomeScore"]]
```

returns you the teams (and corresponding Home/Away scores) you want